Single band multiple raster Exploratory Data Analysis (EDA) in R
I have single band 764 weekly raster files from 2009 to present. Using these files, I want to make seasonal exploratory data analysis (EDA) according to corresponding years. I need to know how I can do that using particular tools in R programming.
I have tried in GIS. But I could not fix there. I have to do it using R programming.

First, let's build some reproducible example:
library(terra)

r = rast(nrows = 18, ncols=36)

# weeks in period 2009-2024
weeks = seq(as.Date("2009-01-01"), as.Date("2024-12-31"), by="weeks")

# create dummy data
setValuesWeeks = function(week, r){
  return(setValues(r, values = sin(as.numeric(week)) + rnorm(ncell(r), mean=0, sd=0.1)))
}

set.seed(123)
rl = lapply(weeks, setValuesWeeks, r = r)
rs = rast(rl)

Then, you have many options to explore the time series. One of the most simple and most used is Seasonal Trend Decomposition.
The challenge here is to return what you need to evaluate the data. Sadly, R language returns only one value from functions, thus it will be computationally expensive. For instance, getting the trend of the times series, pixel-by-pixel, using STL:
stlr = function(x){
  res = stl(ts(x, frequency=52.14, start=c(2009,1)), s.window = 52+1, t.window = 52*5+1)
  return(res$time.series[,'trend'])
}

result = app(rs, stlr)

plot(x=weeks, y=unlist(as.vector(result[5,5])),type='l')


If you want to get seasonal or remainder value, you should apply the function again (that's the computationally expensive side).
